# searching a large amount of text using javascript and html5 storage

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, full-text-search, web-sql

I have a web app that relies on html5 offline storage features so that it can be accessed by the user without an internet connection.  The app essentially just serves html pages and a little bit of css and javascript.

I am trying to add the ability to search the text served on these pages for key words, but because the app isn't guaranteed access to the server it needs to be able to perform these searches on the client side.

My thought is I can store the searchable text in the browser's web sql database and perform the search either through javascript or through the browser's sql api.  I have a few question about the best way to do this:

1) I vaguely remember an article about how to implement something like this, maybe from airbnb?  Does anyone remember such an article?

2) The text is 2,000,000+ words so I would assume that indexOf is going to break down at this data size.  Is there any chance regex will hold up? What are some options for implementing the actual search? (libraries, algorithms, etc.) Any article suggestions for understanding the tradeoffs of string search algorithms if I need to go down that road?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just wrote [a quick benchmark](http://jsfiddle.net/da884/1/) for you and was surprised to find that you could probably get away with using `String.indexOf()`.  I get about 35ms per search, which is about 30 searches per second.

**EDIT:** [a better benchmark](http://jsfiddle.net/da884/7/).  There appears to be some sort of initialization delay, but it looks like `indexOf` is pretty fast.  You could play around with the benchmark and see if it looks like it will work for you.